# Animation starts but does not seem to continue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Im trying to do an animation in ios, I copied a working example (which worked for me) however I edited it to have a longer animation: press the button to start the animation, it shows the first image, but never progresses to through the rest.

Please see my code below!

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize imageView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0001.png"];

self.imageView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(22, 110, 724, 451)];


[self.view insertSubview : self.imageView atIndex:0];


self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 9.0;
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0;

self.imageView.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: [UIImage      imageNamed:@"invasive0001.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0002.png"],//1
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0003.png"],//2
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0004.png"],//3
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0005.png"],//4
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0006.png"],//5
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0007.png"],//6
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0008.png"],//7
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0009.png"],//8
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive00010.png"],//9
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0011.png"],//10
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0012.png"],//11
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0013.png"],//12
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0014.png"],//13
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0015.png"],//14
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0016.png"],//15
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0017.png"],//16
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0018.png"],//17
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0019.png"],//18
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0020.png"],//19
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0021.png"],//19
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0022.png"],//20
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0023.png"],//1
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0024.png"],//2
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0025.png"],//3
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0026.png"],//4
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0027.png"],//5
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0028.png"],//6
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0029.png"],//7
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0030.png"],//8
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0031.png"],//9
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0032.png"],//10
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0033.png"],//11
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0034.png"],//12
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0035.png"],//13
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0036.png"],//14
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0037.png"],//15
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0038.png"],//16
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0039.png"],//17
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0040.png"],//18
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0041.png"],//19
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0042.png"],//20
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0043.png"],//1
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0044.png"],//2
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0045.png"],//3
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0046.png"],//4
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0047.png"],//5
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0048.png"],//6
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0049.png"],//7
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0050.png"],//8
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0051.png"],//9
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0052.png"],//10
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0053.png"],//11
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0054.png"],//12
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0055.png"],//13
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0056.png"],//14
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0057.png"],//15
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0058.png"],//16
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0059.png"],//17
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0060.png"],//18
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0061.png"],//9
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0062.png"],//10
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0063.png"],//11
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0064.png"],//12
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0065.png"],//13
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0066.png"],//14
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0067.png"],//15
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0068.png"],//16
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0069.png"],//17
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0070.png"],//19
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0071.png"],//20
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0072.png"],//1
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0073.png"],//2
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0074.png"],//3
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0075.png"],//4
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0076.png"],//5
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0077.png"],//6
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0078.png"],//7
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0079.png"],//8
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0080.png"],//9
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0081.png"],//10
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0082.png"],//11
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0083.png"],//12
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0084.png"],//13
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0085.png"],//14
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0086.png"],//15
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0087.png"],//16
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0088.png"],//17
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0089.png"],//18
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0090.png"],//19
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0091.png"],//20
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0092.png"],//1
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0093.png"],//2
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0094.png"],//3
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0095.png"],//4
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0096.png"],//5
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0097.png"],//6
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0098.png"],//7
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0099.png"],//8
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0100.png"],//9
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0101.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0102.png"],//1
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0103.png"],//2
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0104.png"],//3
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0105.png"],//4
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0106.png"],//5
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0107.png"],//6
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0108.png"],//7
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0109.png"],//8
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0110.png"],//9
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0111.png"],//10
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0112.png"],//11
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0113.png"],//12
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0114.png"],//13
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0115.png"],//14
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0116.png"],//15
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0117.png"],//16
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0118.png"],//17
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0119.png"],//18
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0120.png"],//19
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0121.png"],//19
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0122.png"],//20
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0123.png"],//1
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0124.png"],//2
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0125.png"],//3
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0126.png"],//4
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0127.png"],//5
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0128.png"],//6
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0129.png"],//7
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0130.png"],//8
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0131.png"],//9
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0132.png"],//10
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0133.png"],//11
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0134.png"],//12
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0135.png"],//13
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0136.png"],//14
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0137.png"],//15
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0138.png"],//16
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0139.png"],//17
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0140.png"],//18
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0141.png"],//19
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0142.png"],//20
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0143.png"],//1
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0144.png"],//2
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0145.png"],//3
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0146.png"],//4
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0147.png"],//5
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0148.png"],//6
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0149.png"],//7
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0150.png"],//8
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0151.png"],//9
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0152.png"],//10
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0153.png"],//11
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0154.png"],//12
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0155.png"],//13
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0156.png"],//14
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0157.png"],//15
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0158.png"],//16
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0159.png"],//17
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0160.png"],//18
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0161.png"],//9
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0162.png"],//10
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0163.png"],//11
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0164.png"],//12
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0165.png"],//13
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0166.png"],//14
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0167.png"],//15
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0168.png"],//16
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0169.png"],//17
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0170.png"],//19
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0171.png"],//20
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0172.png"],//1
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0173.png"],//2
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0174.png"],//3
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0175.png"],//4
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0176.png"],//5
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0177.png"],//6
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0178.png"],//7
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0179.png"],//8
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0180.png"],//9
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0181.png"],//10
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0182.png"],//11
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0183.png"],//12
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0184.png"],//13
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0185.png"],//14
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0186.png"],//15
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0187.png"],//16
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0188.png"],//17
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0189.png"],//18
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0190.png"],//19
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0191.png"],//20
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0192.png"],//1
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0193.png"],//2
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0194.png"],//3
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0195.png"],//4
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0196.png"],//5
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0197.png"],//6
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0198.png"],//7
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0199.png"],//8
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0200.png"],//9
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0201.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0202.png"],//1
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0203.png"],//2
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0204.png"],//3
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0205.png"],//4
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0206.png"],//5
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0207.png"],//6
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0208.png"],//7
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0209.png"],//8
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0210.png"],//9
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0211.png"],//10
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0212.png"],//11
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0213.png"],//12
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0214.png"],//13
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0215.png"],//14
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0216.png"],//15
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0217.png"],//16
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0218.png"],//17
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0219.png"],//18
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0220.png"],//19
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0221.png"],//19
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0222.png"],//20
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0223.png"],//1
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0224.png"],//2
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0225.png"],//3
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0226.png"],//4
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0227.png"],//5
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0228.png"],//6
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0229.png"],//7
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0230.png"],//8
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0231.png"],//9
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0232.png"],//10
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0233.png"],//11
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0234.png"],//12
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0235.png"],//13
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0236.png"],//14
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0237.png"],//15
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0238.png"],//16
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0239.png"],//17
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0240.png"],//18
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0241.png"],//19
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0242.png"],//20
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0243.png"],//1
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0244.png"],//2
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0245.png"],//3
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0246.png"],//4
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0247.png"],//5
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0248.png"],//6
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0249.png"],//7
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0250.png"],//8
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0251.png"],//9
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0252.png"],//10
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0253.png"],//11
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0254.png"],//12
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0255.png"],//13
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0256.png"],//14
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0257.png"],//15
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0258.png"],//16
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0259.png"],//17
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0260.png"],//18
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0261.png"],//9
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0262.png"],//10
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0263.png"],//11
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0264.png"],//12
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0265.png"],//13
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0266.png"],//14
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0267.png"],//15
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0268.png"],//16
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0269.png"],//17
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0270.png"],//19
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0271.png"],//20
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0272.png"],//1
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0273.png"],//2
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0274.png"],//3
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0275.png"],//4
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0276.png"],//5
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0277.png"],//6
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0278.png"],//7
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0279.png"],//8
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0280.png"],//9
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0281.png"],//10
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0282.png"],//11
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0283.png"],//12
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0284.png"],//13
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0285.png"],//14
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0286.png"],//15
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive0287.png"],//16
                                  nil];
//1.5
    self.imageView.animationDuration = 30.0;
    self.imageView.animationRepeatCount=0;

}
//button to press to start animation
-(IBAction)buttonStart:(id)sender{


[imageView startAnimating];
}
```

Thanks All!

**** Update: I tried running it on the device however it crashes when I press the play button, it works fine on the emulator, could this be that there are too many images?

Thanks again.

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause but `[UIImage imageNamed:@"invasive00010.png"]` appears to be named differently from all the others. (should be `invasive0010.png`?)

Comment: The `animationDuration` is the length of the full animation, not per frame. You can't possibly iterate through this many images in 0.4 seconds. Increase the duration to the length of one full animation.

Comment: When you look at the target settings, click on the "Build Phases" section, and expand the "Copy Bundle Resources" section, do you see all of your images listed there? Also, have you checked your `IBOutlet` for this button to make sure your `buttonStart` method is actually getting called? Perhaps put a `NSLog("@d", [imageView.animationImages count]);` inside that `buttonStart` method to (a) confirm it's getting called at all; and (b) that you have as many images in that array as you think you should.

Comment: Thanks rog, yes you are right its ment to be invasive0010 not 00010!

Comment: @Rob - tried both, your sample for NSLog would not work however I did implement a simple NSLog to print pressed whhen the button is pressed, which it did. I know the button works because it loads the first image when the button is pressed, almost like loading in the animation but doesnt continue it. Still nothing is working. All the images are in the bundle also.

Comment: @Mr.Berna, thanks for clearing that up! Took your advice however still no change. The image remains at the first image and doesnt continue to the rest. I know the first few images are very similar however! Its only at invasive0029.png that it begins to change...might the default duration be too short for this? Its really bothering me as I have other animations working (but with less images)

Comment: @gcorkc I'm not sure what you mean by the "NSLog would not work." In your "simple" NSLog when the button is pressed, just have it also tell you how many images are in the array of `animationImages`. What does it say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try loading the image files like below.  You may need to fiddle with the loop and leading zeros.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i=2; i < 288; i++) {
    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"invasive%04d.png", i];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
    if (!image) {
        NSLog(@"Could not load: %@", name);
    }
    else {
        [array addObject:image];
    }
}

self.imageView.animationImages = array;
```

Comment: After the `if` condition you need to have a `else` condition or you will get **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'** if the image is nill then.

Comment: A nil image would not be added to the array.  It would log that it could not be loaded.  That line is just for debugging.  I would actually use a NSAssert.

Comment: @bbarnhart - could you explain to me whats happening with    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"invasive%04d.png", i];  please

Comment: stringWithFormat will take a printf style formatting. Basically it's  `%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier`  [I think this site is easy to understand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Another problem is that you are specifying a frame rate of over 700 frames per second, with 287 frames and a duration of 0.4. Try not setting `self.imageView.animationDuration`, allowing the UIImageView to calculate a default value that will give a 30 frames per second animation. I personally always leave it at the default, only changing it if I want a lower frame rate (longer animation).